# Elemental question for the point at infinity and holomorphic functions

Tags: complex-analysis

The definition of analiticity at $\infty$ says:

> The function $f(z)$ is analytic at $z=\infty$ if the function $g(w)=f(1/w)$ is analytic at $w=0$.

In [Beardon](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0387975896) there is the example

$$
P(z) = a_0+a_1z+\dots+a_n z^n,
$$

with $n>0$ and $a_n\neq0$. Obviuosly $P(\infty)=\infty$, but to prove that "$g(z)$" is holomorphic one has to compute

$$
\frac{1}{P(1/z)}\rightarrow0,
$$

as $z\rightarrow\infty$. My stupid question is, is there a problem with the definition given at the begginning? or why we have to calculate the inverse of the polynomial plus $1/z$ for rational functions?

Comment: $g(z)=P(1/z)$, for a non-constant polynomial, is not holomorphic at $z=0$. All they are doing is proving that $\lim_{z\to0}P(1/z)=\infty$ by proving instead that $\lim_{z\to0} \frac{1}{P(1/z)}=0$. They could have proven the first limit in many other ways.

Comment: Do you know a good refreshing book on rational functions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can think about this in terms of charts in the Riemann Surface. By definition, you can say that a function $f: \overline{\mathbb{C}} \rightarrow \overline{\mathbb{C}}$, where $\overline{\mathbb{C}} = \mathbb{C} \cup \{ \infty \}$, is holomorphic at $z = \infty$ if the function (defined at a neighbourhood of the zero):
$$
g \doteq \phi \circ f \circ \phi^{-1}
$$
is holomorphic at $w = 0$, where $\phi(z) = 1/z = w$ is the local coordinate in this neighbourhood. If you have any background in Differential Topology or in Riemann Surfaces, this will make much more sense. If not, I recommend you to study this concept with this view in mind.

Your condition on the polynomial is exactly what i just described. If your function $f(\infty) = a \in \mathbb{C}$, you can use your first definition (since you can take the local coordinate at the image as the identity).

But as pointed out in the comments, $g(z) = P(1/z)$ is not holomorphic at $z = 0$. Try to prove this using this definition.